# How to get image height and add it to the included Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slider, height

The following is for a slider, and on the very last line it lists a number of default values. One of them is height. This specifies the height of the slider. But I am trying to get it to be variable to the height of the images. Each instance of the slider would have images of the same height, but another page may have images of a different height in the slider.

```
this.each(function() { init(this); });
$.fn.coinslider.defaults = { 
    width:828,
    height:564,
    spw:7,
    sph:5,
    delay:3000,
    sDelay:30,
    opacity:0.7,
    titleSpeed:500,
    effect:'',
    navigation:true,
    links:false,
    hoverPause:true };
})(jQuery);
```

I've found a few ways to find the image height, but I am not sure how to install them correctly into the code below.

I was working with:

```
var img = document.getElementByClass('imageclass');
img.clientHeight;
```

How can I inject that into the following, and replace the static figure in the last line that specifies the height? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

```
(function ($) {
var params = new Array;
var order = new Array;
var images = new Array;
var links = new Array;
var linksTarget = new Array;
var titles = new Array;
var interval = new Array;
var imagePos = new Array;
var appInterval = new Array;
var squarePos = new Array;
var reverse = new Array;
$.fn.coinslider = $.fn.CoinSlider = function (options) {
    init = function (el) {
        order[el.id] = new Array();
        images[el.id] = new Array();
        links[el.id] = new Array();
        linksTarget[el.id] = new Array();
        titles[el.id] = new Array();
        imagePos[el.id] = 0;
        squarePos[el.id] = 0;
        reverse[el.id] = 1;
        params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);
        $.each($('#' + el.id + ' img'), function (i, item) {
            images[el.id][i] = $(item).attr('src');
            links[el.id][i] = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
            linksTarget[el.id][i] = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
            titles[el.id][i] = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
            $(item).hide();
            $(item).next().hide();
        });
        $(el).css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][0] + ')',
            'width': params[el.id].width,
            'height': params[el.id].height,
            'position': 'relative',
            'background-position': 'top left'
        }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-" + el.id + "' />");
        $('#' + el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-" + el.id + "' style='position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");
        $.setFields(el);
        if (params[el.id].navigation) $.setNavigation(el);
        $.transition(el, 0);
        $.transitionCall(el);
    }
    $.setFields = function (el) {
        tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width / params[el.id].spw);
        tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height / params[el.id].sph);
        counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
        tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw * sWidth;
        tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph * sHeight;
        for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
            gapx = tgapx;
            if (gapy > 0) {
                gapy--;
                sHeight = tHeight + 1;
            } else {
                sHeight = tHeight;
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                if (gapx > 0) {
                    gapx--;
                    sWidth = tWidth + 1;
                } else {
                    sWidth = tWidth;
                }
                order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                counter++;
                if (params[el.id].links) $('#' + el.id).append("<a href='" + links[el.id][0] + "' class='cs-" + el.id + "' id='cs-" + el.id + i + j + "' style='width:" + sWidth + "px; height:" + sHeight + "px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
                else $('#' + el.id).append("<div class='cs-" + el.id + "' id='cs-" + el.id + i + j + "' style='width:" + sWidth + "px; height:" + sHeight + "px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");
                $("#cs-" + el.id + i + j).css({
                    'background-position': -sLeft + 'px ' + (-sTop + 'px'),
                    'left': sLeft,
                    'top': sTop
                });
                sLeft += sWidth;
            }
            sTop += sHeight;
            sLeft = 0;
        }
        $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show();
        });
        $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
        });
        $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show();
        });
        $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
        });
        if (params[el.id].hoverPause) {
            $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                params[el.id].pause = true;
            });
            $('.cs-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            });
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseover(function () {
                params[el.id].pause = true;
            });
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).mouseout(function () {
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            });
        }
    };
    $.transitionCall = function (el) {
        clearInterval(interval[el.id]);
        delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw * params[el.id].sph * params[el.id].sDelay;
        interval[el.id] = setInterval(function () {
            $.transition(el)
        }, delay);
    }
    $.transition = function (el, direction) {
        if (params[el.id].pause == true) return;
        $.effect(el);
        squarePos[el.id] = 0;
        appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function () {
            $.appereance(el, order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])
        }, params[el.id].sDelay);
        $(el).css({
            'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]] + ')'
        });
        if (typeof (direction) == "undefined") imagePos[el.id]++;
        else if (direction == 'prev') imagePos[el.id]--;
        else imagePos[el.id] = direction;
        if (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
            imagePos[el.id] = 0;
        }
        if (imagePos[el.id] == -1) {
            imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length - 1;
        }
        $('.cs-button-' + el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
        $('#cs-button-' + el.id + "-" + (imagePos[el.id] + 1)).addClass('cs-active');
        if (titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]) {
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).css({
                'opacity': 0
            }).animate({
                'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
            }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
        } else {
            $('#cs-title-' + el.id).css('opacity', 0);
        }
    };
    $.appereance = function (el, sid) {
        $('.cs-' + el.id).attr('href', links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target', linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
        if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw * params[el.id].sph) {
            clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
            return;
        }
        $('#cs-' + el.id + sid).css({
            opacity: 0,
            'background-image': 'url(' + images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]] + ')'
        });
        $('#cs-' + el.id + sid).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);
        squarePos[el.id]++;
    };
    $.setNavigation = function (el) {
        $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-" + el.id + "'></div>");
        $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
        $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-" + el.id + "' class='cs-prev'></a>");
        $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-" + el.id + "' class='cs-next'></a>");
        $('#cs-prev-' + el.id).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'left': 0,
            'z-index': 1001,
            'line-height': '30px',
            'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.transition(el, 'prev');
            $.transitionCall(el);
        }).mouseover(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show()
        });
        $('#cs-next-' + el.id).css({
            'position': 'absolute',
            'top': 0,
            'right': 0,
            'z-index': 1001,
            'line-height': '30px',
            'opacity': params[el.id].opacity
        }).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.transition(el);
            $.transitionCall(el);
        }).mouseover(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).show()
        });
        $("<div id='cs-buttons-" + el.id + "' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-' + el.id));
        for (k = 1; k < images[el.id].length + 1; k++) {
            $('#cs-buttons-' + el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-" + el.id + "' id='cs-button-" + el.id + "-" + k + "'>" + k + "</a>");
        }
        $.each($('.cs-button-' + el.id), function (i, item) {
            $(item).click(function (e) {
                $('.cs-button-' + el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
                $(this).addClass('cs-active');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el, i);
                $.transitionCall(el);
            })
        });
        $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id + ' a').mouseout(function () {
            $('#cs-navigation-' + el.id).hide();
            params[el.id].pause = false;
        });
        $("#cs-buttons-" + el.id) /*.css({'right':'50%','margin-left':-images[el.id].length*15/2-5,'position':'relative'})*/
        ;
    }
    $.effect = function (el) {
        effA = ['random', 'swirl', 'rain', 'straight'];
        if (params[el.id].effect == '') eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random() * (effA.length))];
        else eff = params[el.id].effect;
        order[el.id] = new Array();
        if (eff == 'random') {
            counter = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                    order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            $.random(order[el.id]);
        }
        if (eff == 'rain') {
            $.rain(el);
        }
        if (eff == 'swirl') $.swirl(el);
        if (eff == 'straight') $.straight(el);
        reverse[el.id] *= -1;
        if (reverse[el.id] > 0) {
            order[el.id].reverse();
        }
    }
    $.random = function (arr) {
        var i = arr.length;
        if (i == 0) return false;
        while (--i) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var tempi = arr[i];
            var tempj = arr[j];
            arr[i] = tempj;
            arr[j] = tempi;
        }
    }
    $.swirl = function (el) {
        var n = params[el.id].sph;
        var m = params[el.id].spw;
        var x = 1;
        var y = 1;
        var going = 0;
        var num = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var dowhile = true;
        while (dowhile) {
            num = (going == 0 || going == 2) ? m : n;
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                order[el.id][c] = x + '' + y;
                c++;
                if (i != num) {
                    switch (going) {
                    case 0:
                        y++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        x++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        y--;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        x--;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            going = (going + 1) % 4;
            switch (going) {
            case 0:
                m--;
                y++;
                break;
            case 1:
                n--;
                x++;
                break;
            case 2:
                m--;
                y--;
                break;
            case 3:
                n--;
                x--;
                break;
            }
            check = $.max(n, m) - $.min(n, m);
            if (m <= check && n <= check) dowhile = false;
        }
    }
    $.rain = function (el) {
        var n = params[el.id].sph;
        var m = params[el.id].spw;
        var c = 0;
        var to = to2 = from = 1;
        var dowhile = true;
        while (dowhile) {
            for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
                order[el.id][c] = i + '' + parseInt(to2 - i + 1);
                c++;
            }
            to2++;
            if (to < n && to2 < m && n < m) {
                to++;
            }
            if (to < n && n >= m) {
                to++;
            }
            if (to2 > m) {
                from++;
            }
            if (from > to) dowhile = false;
        }
    }
    $.straight = function (el) {
        counter = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= params[el.id].sph; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++) {
                order[el.id][counter] = i + '' + j;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    $.min = function (n, m) {
        if (n > m) return m;
        else return n;
    }
    $.max = function (n, m) {
        if (n < m) return m;
        else return n;
    }
    this.each(function () {
        init(this);
    });
};
$.fn.coinslider.defaults = {
    width: 828,
    height: 564,
    spw: 7,
    sph: 5,
    delay: 3000,
    sDelay: 30,
    opacity: 0.7,
    titleSpeed: 500,
    effect: '',
    navigation: true,
    links: false,
    hoverPause: true
};
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Readable code, copy the contents of that wall, and paste it at http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, you can determine the images height with jQuery's `height()` method. And your code is a mess, clean it up if you seriously want somebody to take a look.

Comment: sorry, it was the min version of the js. fixed.

Comment: @Matt: Add new post with your answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Niko's suggestion worked the best, `height: $('#attachment-full').height()`

Answer (score 3):

The last line is for the **default options**, it seems this jQuery plugin can be initialized with custom options :

```
var heightYouWish = 400;
$('#myDom').CoinSlider({'height':heightYouWish});
```

I would just advice that if you are using jQuery, you should use $('myImgSelector').height() instead of your height code for better compliance...